# Exclude emails from stylization of decimals

Tags: php, woocommerce

The below code should not impact WooCommerce Admin (works good already) and it should not impact WooCommerce emails (doesn't work).

Can you help to fix this part about **class_exists** or another way to make sure that this custom code doesn't impact the WooCommerce emails? Thanks

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'ts_woo_decimal_price', 10, 5 );
function ts_woo_decimal_price( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_places, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {
    // Not on backend
    if ( ! is_admin() OR ! class_exists( 'WC_Emails' ) ) {
        $price_data = explode($decimal_separator, $formatted_price);
        return $price_data[0] . '<sup>' . $price_data[1] . '</sup>';
    }
    return $formatted_price;
}
```

Comment: I don’t think a check using `class_exists` makes much sense here to begin with; just because a class _exists_, does not necessarily mean that the current context has anything to do with that. (A lot of classes might _exist_ at this point, simply because they have been auto-loaded before already.)

Comment: CBroe, ok so what would you suggest to make sure that this code doesn't impact the default WooCommerc emails (new order, pending order...)?